# Optimising Jquery code - Adding and removing classes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I am currently learning js and jquery to assist me with my designs, a common problem that I am having is that I can get it to do what I want it to but I have no idea if the way in which it has been coded is efficient. Could anyone see a better way to code this:

```
$(".cal-check a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(".agenda").addClass("active");
});

$(".agenda .close-panel").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(".agenda").removeClass("active");
});
```

I want to click on a calendar event then it adds the class active to another class within the calendar called agenda which then brings up the agenda. I then remove it by clicking on a close panel element. Many thanks

Comment: I prevent the default action as I am clicking on an active link

Comment: On the whole this looks fine.

Comment: Looks fine - the only thing more efficient maybe would be to cache the .agenda selector above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cache the .agenda selector like so:

```
var $agenda = $(".agenda");

$(".cal-check a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $agenda.addClass("active");
});

$agenda.find(".close-panel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $agenda.removeClass("active");
});​
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your responses. I feel that caching the selector is the best improvement that I could make. I have to make a class as I am using css transitions to go between an active or unactive state. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not changing classes, that will usually be rather intensive on the browser, because one class change will mean that all the classes have to be reparsed. This is usually very bad for more aggressive stuff, like animation, but if you have performance considerations, you should take that into advisement.

Comment: If you're changing the CSS with JavaScript I could believe this, but not if you're changing `node.className`, can you cite somewhere which shows this?

Comment: I read it on various sites that were mostly JS/CSS animation related.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is already efficient.
Just something that might help in the future is to try and dive into the DOM as little as possible. In this small example it wont make a difference but for example create a variable for agendaClass instead of using jquery every time to fetch it.

```
var agendaClass = $(".agenda");

$(".cal-check a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
agendaClass .addClass("active");
});

$(".agenda .close-panel").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
agendaClass .removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be efficient enough. How you can optimize your code strongly depends on your DOM structure.

Behind the scene, jQuery with its Sizzle search engine will use built in methods for DOM search, if those are available (native search will be always faster than search done with JS). In your case everything should be Ok, especially in modern browsers, as they have [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) and `.cal-check a` and `.agenda` selectors will be executed with that built in method. Also, there is [getElementByClassName](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname) which could be used to find `.agenda`.

Both of those methods are supported by most of modern browsers (provided links have a list of supported browser), so talking about browsers like IE8+, Firefox and Chrome will be fast enough with your selectors. At the same time IE7 has no functions like above and Sizzle will be forced to go through numerouse elements to find elements you are looking for. Maybe you can   limit that amount specifying some container with id, in that case it will look inside that elements only:
`$("#someId .agenda")`, for instance. You may want additionally add some tag: `$("#someId div.agenda")`. This way you will limit amount of elements to search with divs (getElementsByTagName could be used) inside `#someId` (getElementById). That way you may increase speed in IE7 and other old browsers with no support of `getElementByClassName` and `querySelector`

Plus, you may cache search results as it was already mentioned here.